# Cannot kill Bitdefender process after uninstalling it, no launch daemons found

Tags: macos, high-sierra, permission, launchd

Recently, I installed Bitdefender Antivirus. I wanted to remove it after the trial period. After uninstalling it via CCleaner, moving all stuff from Librar, I found there is still an agent up and running and I cannot disable. I cannot kill that process even as root:

bdagent - pid 65

```
sudo su - 
kill -9 65
-sh: kill: (65) - Operation not permitted
```

Killing it via Activity Monitor doesn't work either.

Output of `ps` is:

```
root# ps -ef | grep defender
    0    65     1   0 11:08PM ??         6:49.98 /Library/Bitdefender/Central/Agent/bdagentd
    0   211     1   0 11:08PM ??         0:00.40 /Library/Bitdefender/AVP/antivirus.bundle/BDUpdDaemon
    0   212     1   0 11:08PM ??         0:08.25 /Library/Bitdefender/AVP/antivirus.bundle/BDLDaemon
    0   213     1   0 11:08PM ??         0:00.23 /Library/Bitdefender/AVP/common.bundle/BDCoreIssues
    0   224     1   0 11:08PM ??         0:00.12 /Library/Bitdefender/Central/Agent/bdcredentialsd
  501   513     1   0 11:08PM ??         0:01.13 /Library/Bitdefender/AVP/AntivirusforMac.app/Contents/MacOS/AntivirusforMac
```

The Bitdefender folder is:

```
drwxr-xr-x    4 root  wheel   128 Jul  2 19:32 Bitdefender
```

I cannot remove it, even as root, I cannot `chown`, nothing.

Is there any way to just remove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I managed to fix it.

TLDR:

1. Boot into recovery (hold CMD+R on startup)
2. Go to Disk utility, mount your OS X partition
3. Go back, launch terminal (top bar -> utilities)
4. Remove the `AVP` folder

```bsh
cd /Volumes/<mac_drive>
cd Library/Bitdefender

# take a backup of the entire antivirus folder
tar czvf AVP.tar.gz AVP
rm -rf AVP
```

https://www.bitdefender.com/support/how-to-uninstall-antivirus-for-mac-if-the-standard-uninstaller-doesn&039;t-work-1722.html

Resolved thanks to [@user90735](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/90735/user90735)

Comment: Good to know this as I'll be going through it soon. BitDefender is just too much!

Answer (score 4):

It is blocked by one or more of the extensions it installs: FileProtect.kext, SelfProtect.kext, TMProtection.kext

You should always use Bitdefender's uninstaller at /Applications/Bitdefender/BitdefenderUninstaller and not these other apps you mentioned. Follow the instructions at https://www.bitdefender.com/consumer/support/answer/1784/

If that doesn't work, that page links to another page that covers the manual removal process. https://www.bitdefender.com/consumer/support/answer/1446/

Comment: I finally had to completely remove BD, because it was consistently eating up 100% of my CPU.